# [Postfix][Dovecot] Automatically forward a sent message under the identity of an email list to all other members of that list

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I am running Postfix 3.8.4, Dovecot 2.3.20 (with pigeon hole sieve support) and OpenLDAP 2.6.4 as the backend for account and alias management.

Let's assume I have two mail accounts `jane.doe@my-domain.tld` and `john.doe@my-domain.tld` as well as an alias `doe@my-domain.tld` which forwards any incoming mail to both mail accounts. Moreover, both mail accounts (i.e. `jane.doe@my-domain.tld` and `john.doe@my-domain.tld`) has the right to sent mail using the alias `doe@my-domain.tld` as the sender envelope address instead of their personal sender identity.

If any of the actual mail accounts submit/send a mail in the name of the alias, I want that mail to be forwarded to the other mail account in addition to the actual recipient. The goal is that all members of such an alias (aka mailing list) are automatically informed that some member of the mailing list has sent a mail in their name.

How do I implement such a feature?

Please note that the example with two mail account on the mailing list is only an example to keep it simply. In reality, the alias/mailing list can have arbitrary many members.

Detailed example of expected behavior:

1. Someone, e.g. `friend@foreign-domain.tld` sends a mail to `doe@my-domain.tld`
2. Postfix receives the mail, resolves the alias and transports two copies of the mail to Dovecot (via LMTP) for recipient `jane.doe@my-domain.tld` and `john.doe@my-domain.tld`
3. Lets say, Jane decides to reply. Jane's mail client submits a mail to Postfix for `friend@foreign-domain.tld` as the recipient and with `doe@my-domain.tld` as the sender identity.
4. Postfix relays the mail to `friend@foreign-domain.tld` but also transports a copy of the mail for `john.doe@my-domain.tld` to Dovecot
5. John is able to notice that Jane has already replied to `friend@foreign-domain.tld`

For Postfix, I found the configuration directive `sender_bbc_maps` which somewhat does what I want, but unfortunately, this only allows a single value to be returned per sender identity and that value must not be an alias. Hence, `sender_bbc_maps` seems to be too restricted for my use case.